# setting the checked attribute of radio input for first item in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a input tag which want to set the checked attribute on a condition in MVC razor. so I did this

```
    @{ 
        bool firstItem = true;
     }
    @foreach (var item in Model.userAddresses)
        {
           <div>
              <div class="d-lg-inline-block">
                 <input asp-for="SelectedAddress" type="radio" value="@item.Id"   @(@firstItem == true ? "checked" : "")  /> @item.FullAddress<br />
              </div>
           </div>
      @if (firstItem == true)
          firstItem = false;
        }
```

but the   @(@firstItem == true ? "checked" : "") doesn't work setting the checked attribute for the radio input for first item.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to

```
   <input asp-for="SelectedAddress" type="radio" value="@item.Id"   checked="@firstItem"  /> @item.FullAddress<br />
```

and it worked